# Hi im brand new to python 3 and looking to calculating floats in a list that has both floats and strings as part of the list

Tags: python-3.x

Hi i am new here and to python been studying on codecademy and loving it. im about halfway through the course but had an idea for a project that i thought would be easy with what i know so far.

I'm stuck tho. my idea is to make a program that adds up all my bills e.g loans, credit cards, phone bill's.

i wanted to put it all in a list with the name of the bill and the amount it cost, to then be able to total either, everything in the list or just select bills.

my list will be about 10 or so items long but trying to just get it to work with 2 for now be for i type to much and it not work.

so this is what i have

```
bills = [['natwest loan', 263.09], ['my phone',  51.50]]
total = bills[0] + bills[1]
print(str(total))
```

so this just ads both parts of the list together, i want to just add the floats and get a total.i want it to basicaly so this.

```
total = 263.09 + 51.50
```

i cant figure out where im going wrong.

hope i made sense and thanks for any help

Comment: `bills[0] == ['natwest loan', 263.09]`. How does one extract the second element of that list? `bills[0][1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
>>> bills = [['natwest loan', 263.09], ['my phone',  51.50]]
>>> 
>>> total_bills = sum([x[1] for x in bills])
>>> total_bills
314.59
>>> total_bills = str(total_bills)
>>> total_bills
'314.59'
>>>
```

Your bills are actually at the `second index i.e [1]` of each element inside your list `bills`

Each element inside your list is an individual entry

> Index 0 -> Telling you whats is it for

> Index 1 -> The amount

You need to iterate over the list and only add up elements at the Index 1

Comment: awesome thank you for the quick response. so writing the code in this way would it add up my entire list? saving me going through each element one at a time?  this is the first time i have seen sum used.

Comment: Yes essentially you are looping through the entire `bills` in the above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You've written out a very nice and well thought out question.

The problem in your code is that you aren't accessing the right value. When you write-

```py
bills = [['natwest loan', 263.09], ['my phone',  51.50]]
total = bills[0] + bills[1]
```

You are now accessing the first and second items in `bills`, which are `['natwest loan', 263.09]` and `['my phone',  51.50]`. What you want to add is that for each of these items, you want to access the second item in *them* (which are the prices).

```py
bills = [['natwest loan', 263.09], ['my phone',  51.50]]

# The extra [1] here specifies that you want to access the second item of the nested arrays
total = bills[0][1] + bills[1][1]

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want will be like this :

```
bills = [['natwest loan', 263.09], ['my phone',  51.50]]
total = bills[0][1] + bills[1][1]
print(str(total))
```

You want to tell the code where the value is in the list. that is why you use bills[0][1] to tell the code that the float is in the second place of the list

Answer (score -1):

access to nested list is incorrect

you may try this

bills = [['natwest loan', 263.09], ['my phone',  51.50]]
total = int(bills[0][1]) + int(bills[1][1])
print(total)